# Setfocus to textbox from JavaScript after just creating the textbox with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, focus

So I just created a textbox with JavaScript like this:

**EDIT: Added the len variable**

```
var len = tbl.rows.length;
                     var rtb = tbl.insertRow(len);
                     var cName = rtb.insertCell(0);
                     var cDis = rtb.insertCell(1);
                     var cDur = rtb.insertCell(2);
                     cName.innerHTML = '<input type="text"  name="tbName1' + len + '" value="' + selected_text + '" >';
                     cDis.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="tbDis1' + len + '" id="tbDis1' + len + '" >';
                     cDur.innerHTML = '<input type="text"  name="tbDur1' + len + '" >';
                     var txtBox = document.getElementById('tbDist1' + len);
                     txtBox.focus();
```

**EDIT:Changed the second to last line.** Still get this error: txtBox is null
 txtBox.focus();

The last line isn't working.  After I create the textbox, I can't set focus to it.  Is there any way of doing so?

Comment: You are still missing the 't' when creating the text field.

Comment: Notice it says "tbDis1" + len and you're trying to get "tbDist1" + len

Comment: I'd suggest using createElement and appendChild vs. innerHTML -- cleaner and more standards compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum... you're creating the textbox by saying `id="tbDis1' + len + '"` but you're accessing it by doing `'tbDist1' + (len - 1)`... why? I am not sure about the context, but that would try to focus the previously added textbox, if any. Also, you're creating it with `tbDis` and trying to get to it by using `tbDist`. Missing a `t` in there. Setting the id as `id="tbDist1' + len + '"` and accessing it with `'tbDist1' + (len)` should do the trick.

Comment: I was trying to get the textbox before but it didn't work.  Changed the code and still get null for textbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the value of `txtBox` you will see it is undefined. You try to get the element with id `tbDist1 + (len-1)`, but you create an element with id `tbDis1 + len`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it is supposed to work: you have tbDis and len before, then tbDist (notice: t) and len-1 after. Weird... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Err, it looks like a typo. You're asking for (afaict) `tbDist1`, but creating `tbDis1`.

[Edit: marius also spotted `len` vs `len-1` which I missed.]

Answer (score 0):

I can't call the textbox and idk. Why?!!

--> var txtBox = document.getElementById('tbDist1' + len);

Answer (score 0):

I have this simple code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="f1">

<asp:Label id="tt"  runat="server" Text="Label" onclick="lblClick()"></asp:Label>

</form>
<script type ="text/javascript">

          function lblClick() {
             document.forms[0].tt.Text ="java";// here is the problem .. and idk why?
          }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```